# How to change the size of a plot with a legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My legend gets cut off:

[image: screenshot of plot with legend cut off]

If I change

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6.29, 3.54))
```

to

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6.29, 8))
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But I want that the plot stays the same size, it just should go longer vertically so that the full legend will be shown.

What can I do?

Comment: can you add the code for your plot that moved the legend to that location?

Comment: plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
           shadow=True, ncol=1,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you have to play with **bbox_to_anchor** keyboard argument in order to place your legend outside of your axes and add a convenient space.
See [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

Comment: already checked

Comment: and this is not even my problem... my problem is that my legend is getting cutted of

Comment: In this case save your figure like this: fig.savefig('my_image.png',format='png',  bbox_inches='tight') it will prevent to crop the legend.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I got for running the "almost" same code which shows all the legend:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6.29, 3.54))
dev_y1= np.array([112.95, 117.62, 43.67, 85.64,51.37])
dev_y2= np.array([21.81 , 42.34, 23.82, 61.67,46.23])
dev4x4real = np.array([30.63 ,61.19 , 35.71, 90.53 , 60.33])
dev_x2= np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

plt.plot(dev_x2,dev_y1, 'ro')
#popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, dev_x2, dev_y1)
xFit= np.arange(0.0, 5, 0.01)

plt.plot(dev_y1, dev_y2,color='r', linestyle='-',label=f'Ideales DOE 125 \u03bcJ <= 0,3 \u03bcm F(x) = {round(1)} * e^({round(1)}*x)') 
plt.plot(dev_y1, dev_y2,color='r', linestyle='-',label=f'Ideales DOE 125 \u03bcJ <= 0,3 \u03bcm F(x) = {round(1)} * e^({round(1)}*x)') 
plt.plot(dev_y1, dev_y2,color='r', linestyle='-',label=f'Ideales DOE 125 \u03bcJ <= 0,3 \u03bcm F(x) = {round(1)} * e^({round(1)}*x)') 
plt.ylabel('Herstellungsrate: Mikrostrukturen pro Sekunde')

plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
           shadow=True, ncol=1,)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what version of matplotlib are you running

Comment: 3.3.4 is the version

Comment: mine is 3.4.3 maybe that is why?

Comment: nope but the post below just solved my prob